# Using Next.js with SSR on AWS Amplify, Environment Variables NOT being carried through to auto-created Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I have a Next.js app with SSR which relies on environment variables.  When I deploy the app to AWS Amplify, 2 Lambda functions are created.

I have my environment variables setup in Amplify, however, those variables are NOT set in the Lambda functions that are created during the build.  If I set the environment variables manually on the functions, they are removed during the next build.

Any ideas on how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 10):

The amplify team have been updating this issue in github here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1987

Here is the way they are suggesting to do this:

1. Add your desired environment variable in the Amplify Console like normal (steps)
2. Update (or create) your next.config.js file with the environment variable you added in the Amplify Console. E.g if you created an environment variable named MY_ENV_VAR in the console in step 1) above, then you would add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    MY_ENV_VAR: process.env.MY_ENV_VAR
  }
};
```

3. Now after your next build you will be able to reference your environment variable (process.env.MY_ENV_VAR) in your SSR lambdas!

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: This answer did not work for me.. One of my repo's environment works fine with aws-amplify other repos don't seam to work

Comment: This did not work for me. Instead I added the variables to the Amplify build script in AWS Console

Answer (score 0):

Amplify Hosting supports adding environment variables to your application's builds by setting them in the project's configuration in the Amplify console. However, a Next.js server component doesn't have access to those environment variables by default.

To make specific environment variables accessible to Next.js, you can modify the Amplify build specification file to set them in the environment files that Next.js recognizes.

`- env | grep -e MY_ENV_VAR >> .env.production`

You need to set this under your build settings, to look something like this:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e MY_ENV_VAR >> .env.production
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
      - .next/cache/**/*
```

Follow the documentation here: [Making environment variables accessible to server-side runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-environment-variables.html)

Also, remember to [add the environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) in the Amplify console

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the docs in aws for SSR environment variables.

TLDR:
Add

```
commands:
    - env | grep -e DB_HOST -e DB_USER -e DB_PASS >> .env.production
```

If the variables exist in your build environment, the .env.production file will contain the following environment variables.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASS=mypassword
```

Remember to set the env variables in the secrets manager section inside your app.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-environment-variables.html